# Websphere 8.5 restful APIs to find queue and topic details

Tags: java, websphere

we have application(Java based) on which other 8-10 application are dependent.
They are connecting to different Queue/Topics etc to our application.
Many times these queue/topic names get changes and other teams are chasing us for the changes.

So I am working on creating standalone application , which will invoke restful APIs from WebSphere using Java and will provide them details to specific environment(using some simple UI). (I don't want to use database to store queue/topic details which is manual work . Wanted real time Queue/Topic details from IBM WebSphere ,which is hosted in our environment)

I checked IBM WebSphere documentation but didnt get what I am looking for.
Also if there are any APIs for such , how I can authenticate that API (will there be token etc)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere does not have REST api for this. You need to write your own java application that will connect to Websphere's Deployment Manager (dmgr) via SOAP and query for MQ , and then expose  via REST.

See for jython example... https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/JMS_queues_monitoring_scripts_provided_by_WebSphere_Level_2_support?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

To list the Queues / Topics that are defined in a WAS server, one way to go is to use JMX and MBeans, ie write a program that will initiate a JMX connection, locate the SIB running in WAS, retrieve the MBeans associated to the Queues/Topics and request detailed information on them

For this, you can also use a tool like [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/releases) that does exactly that (and much more)
(To be fair, I'm the author of JMSToolBox..)